# Create a Table in different File-group with EF core code-first

Tags: sql-server, code-first, ef-core-5.0, c#-9.0, filegroup

I want to create a table in the "Secondary" **file group** which has been created previously in the SQL Server 2016. I want to create this table with **EF core code-first**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution and I want to share it.

1. Before creating a Table or adding your Tables’ DbSet in your ApplicationDbContext, create an empty migration with this code in PMC.

```
PM> add-migration CreateSecondaryFileGroup
```

2. Write the SQL query for creating your **filegroup** and its **Physical file** in the “Up” method.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
     //create FILEGROUP 
     migrationBuilder.Sql(
         " EXEC('ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] ADD FILEGROUP [Secondary]')",
         suppressTransaction: true);

     //Create Physical file
     migrationBuilder.Sql(
         "ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] " +
                "ADD FILE " +
                "( " +
                    "NAME = 'Secondary_Data', " +
                    "FILENAME = '[yourFileDirectory]' " +
                    //for example:
                    //"FILENAME = 'D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Abby_Data2.mdf' " +
                ") " +
                "TO FILEGROUP Secondary",
                suppressTransaction:true
            );
}
```

3. Then in PMC run this code to update your Database and create the filegroup.

```
PM> update-database
```

4. Now add your tables’ DbSet in the ApplicationDbContext file, (my table name is Category)

```
public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

5. Now create a new migration file in order to create the table in your database in your specific filegroup (for me the filegroup name is Secondary) with this code in PMC

```
PM> add-migration CreateCategoryTableInSecondaryFileGroup
```

6. Now in the “Up” method of migration file you should add SQL query to “create cluster Index of the table again” with **SQL method** of **migrationBuilder**.

**One solution to create or move a table to another filegroup is to create Clustered Index in the specific filegroup.
The clustered index is the primary key of the “Category” table whose name is “PK_Category”**

[for more information](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5832/move-sql-server-tables-to-different-filegroups/)

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
      migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
      name: "Category",
      columns: table => new
      {
           Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
           Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
           DisplayOrder = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
       },
       constraints: table =>
       {
             table.PrimaryKey("PK_Category", x => x.Id);
       });
       ///// this below code is the key point
       ///// you should write the below code

       migrationBuilder.Sql(
          "CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Category ON Category (Id)"+  
          " WITH(DROP_EXISTING = ON) "+
                " ON Secondary"
               , suppressTransaction:true);
}
```

7. Finally, run this code to update the database in PMC.

```
PM> update-database
```